# not able to loop through an object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending some values to server side using jquery post. And as a response I am getting back string. Then I am taking that and converting into an object by using JSON.parse()...when I am looking at the console log i am seeing the object, which looks fine to me. Now when I am trying to loop through the object and trying to retrieve values I am not able to iterate through it. I cant figure out what am I missing here. I am sending the value on an on change event..so basically the for loop would run every time on change event

Here is my js

```
$(function(){
    var categoryChoiceVal = '';
    var x = [];
    var html = '';
    $('select').change(function() {
        categoryChoiceVal = $('.categoryChoice option:selected').text().replace(/ /g, '%20');
        $.post("ajax.php", { categoryChoiceVal:categoryChoiceVal},function(data) {

            x = $.parseJSON(data)
            console.log(x);
        }); 
        $.each(x, function(){
            html += this.address;
        });
        $('.dataContainer').html(html);
    });

});
```

here is the page where I am doing this. 
http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/phpDataOperation/eventcCalendar/testOne.php

Comment: Same question is asked ten times a day. Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your code in your callback:

```
$.post("ajax.php", { categoryChoiceVal:categoryChoiceVal},function(data) {
     x = $.parseJSON(data)
     console.log(x);

     $.each(x, function(){
          html += this.address;
     });
     $('.dataContainer').html(html);
});
```

`$.post` is asynch. When you call `$.post`, the response from server does not arrive yet. By putting inside the callback, you're assured that the response has arrived when your code is run.

Comment: @Khanh--I am getting undefined if I am doing that

Comment: @soum: what is `undefined`?

Comment: @Khanh--The output is undefined. You should be able to see it from the link. If you need to see my php code let me know I can share it too

Comment: @soum: I see your x is an object containing an array of items which is where you need your data. Just change your code to `$.each(x.items, function(){`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to parse a json response using `$.post`. Notice in the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) there is a fourth parameter `dataType`.

For example:

```
$.post( "test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" }, function( data ) {
  console.log( data.name ); // John
  console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
}, "json");
```

No need to parse it.

The data is accessed only in the success callback, as in that example. Move your loop into your success callback.

Comment: @joe-but I am actually doing this server side
$json = json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;

thats the reason I am converting into an object. Should I not approach it like then?

Comment: JQuery will automatically parse the json for you. You do not need to parse it yourself.